# html li unwanted background on touch

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web-applications

I'm currently working on a website and I experienced a strange behavior for list items. As soon as I touch a li element inside an ul element the list item gets a background (iOS saferi lightgrey and android chrome some kind of blue). Look at this:

This is how it looks like

[image]

(The second item "Linie 42")

I tried following css styles to remove it:

```
li, li:hover, li:active, li:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}
```

However it seems to have nothing to do with these css attributes.

Also this happens only on mobile browsers. I don't have this on Chrome for Windows / Safari on OS X.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `background:none!important!` ?

Comment: yup, but that didn't work either. It additionally said for background-color "mismatched property value". But this didn't work for background too

Comment: Try with [**chrome://inspect/#devices**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en)

Comment: Did that for safari on iOS and Mac but I didn't find any indication for the problem. Also I think if I fix it for iOS Safari it will fix that for chrome on Android too

Comment: Did you try with this ? ::selection {
    color: red; 
    background: yellow;
}

Comment: Try this: `* {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
}`

Comment: @Paran0a This adds fancy color and background for the selection additionally to the grey / blue background on touch

Comment: @RayonDabre Well I cannot select the text now (which is good in my opinion) the background like on the image still stays

Comment: Just as a last attempt, Try using `!important`

Comment: @RayonDabre Still not working. Looks like user select only disables the ability to select any text but is not affecting the styles for the element (not in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe you need to override [`-webkit-touch-callout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout) as When a target is touched and held on iPhone OS, Safari displays a callout information about the link. This property allows disabling that behavior.

Try this `css` properties:

```
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none!important;
  -webkit-user-select: none!important;
}
```